# JsonResponse возвращает сам себя - django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, django

Всем доброго времени суток.

Мне нужно сделать запрос через ajax.

Для реализации сайта я использую django.

Код:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Data:</h2>
    <br>
    <div id="displayData">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'display/',
                success: (function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    document.getElementById("displayData").innerHTML = response;
                })
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

класс `StockSerializer`:

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = '__all__'
```

функция `display()`:

```
def display(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = Stock.objects.all()
        serializer = StockSerializer(data, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

`Stock`:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

Что я сделал неправильно ?

Почему функция `display()` возвращяет ту же страницу, что и была, а не данные таблицы `Stocks`?

Comment: а какой вывод print(serializer.data) ?

Comment: Модель Stock в студию :)

Comment: Михаил, добавил)